# java Jtable with Custom Model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I am tryiong to fire a change in one of my Jtable.

I have a Parser Class and a commandItem class;

```
public class CommandItem {    
  private Integer quantity;
  private final MenuItem item;
  private Double totalPrice;
  public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
  }   
  public MenuItem getMenuItem(){
    return item;
  }
  public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.calculatePrice();
  }

  public CommandItem(Integer quantity, MenuItem item) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.item = item;
    this.calculatePrice();      
  }    
  private void calculatePrice(){
    this.totalPrice = this.quantity * this.item.getPrice();        
  }
  public Double getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
  }    
}

public class MenuParser {
  private ArrayList<CommandItem> commandItems;

  public ArrayList<CommandItem>  getCommandItems(){
    return commandItems;
  }

  //somewhere in the code
  commandItems.add( add(new CommandItem( 2, item));
  Menu.updateTable(commandItems);

}
```

and in my Frame :

```
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  private static ModelCommandItems model;
  private static JTable table;

  public Menu() {
    initComponents();

    menuParser = new MenuParser();


    Menu.model = new ModelCommandItems((this.menuParser.getCommandItems()));        
    //at this stage, model is empty
    Menu.table = new JTable(Menu.model);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(Menu.table);
    jPanel6.add(scrollPane);
  }

  public static void updateTable(ArrayList<CommandItem>  items){
    Menu.model.setData(items);
    Menu.table.setModel(Menu.model);
  }
```

My ModelCommandItems table model is pretty much following standards

```
public class ModelCommandItems implements TableModel {

  private final String[] columnNames;

  private ArrayList<CommandItem> data;

  public ModelCommandItems(ArrayList<CommandItem> data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.columnNames = new String[]{"quantity", "name", "price"};
  }

  public void setData(ArrayList<CommandItem> data) {
    this.data = data;        
  }
```

I can't get my table to actually show the content of the arrayList.

Comment: First of all `static` is not your friend, this is going to cause you no end of issues if you want to use multiple instances of any of the classes within the same JVM.  Second, extend your `ModelCommandItems` class from `AbstractTableModel`, it will take care of much of the house keeping requirements of `TableModel`

Comment: for why reason you need to hold two similair arrays CommandItem & TableModel,

Comment: @mKorbel I have the commandItems array already defined in the parser class. And I need to get this array displayed in a Jtable, after reading the oracle doc, I had to  duplicate it in a tabelModel. Maybe there is anotehr way. I am new to JAVA.

Comment: @Cooluhuru yes correct if is main array for application, search for model based on (util)List of Lists, then change your array to List too, you model is incomplete, and implemented methods missed notifiers (fireXxxXxx) otherwise nothing is displayed, added, changed, removed in JTables view

Answer (score 0):

Here You have to check .. "ArrayList" Column values should match with "quantity", "name", "price" values, Means Array Column item also should be in 3.

Answer (score 0):

Beside @MadProgrammer comments, you didn't tell the table from where it should take the value that it should contain.

To do that, you need to extend your `ModelCommandItems` class from `AbstractTableModel`

**For Example**:

```
public class ModelCommandItems extends AbstractTableModel {

List<Object[]> list; // init list with your data

public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    // check the list size before
    return list.get(0).length;
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Object[] row = list.get(rowIndex);
    return row[columnIndex];
}

}
```

Comment: How do I init the JTable with the AbstracttableModel ? I have an  Exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: javax.swing.JTable.<init>

Comment: its very basic, you can pass the list in constructor, or create a setter method.